# Frequency of motor vibration with different voltage

Tags: motor, frequency, datasheet, vibration

I'm using a motor shown in the link below.

http://www.adafruit.com/product/1201

The product page is not showing the detail of how the frequency of vibration changes with different voltages. I sent email to Adafruit, but they said they don't have any information about that nor data sheet for the motor.

Do you have any information about this or do you know where I can get the data sheet of the motor?

Answer (score 2):

Being a DC motor, it's probably proportional to the voltage, more or less. So the quoted 11,000 RPM at 5V is around 180Hz, I would expect 100Hz at about 2.8V.

If the voltage is too low, the motor will stall and you'll get 0Hz.

Edit: Here's an excerpt from a datasheet for a similar (lower voltage and 12,500 RPM @3V) device:

[image: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf]

As you can see, it varies from 220 Hz at 3V down to about 100Hz where it stalls.

Answer (score 0):

For $2 I would buy one and create that curve myself. It will have some dependency on the material the vibrator is mounted in.

If exact frequency of vibration is important to you, you might consider using a [stepper motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor) or an [audio surface transducer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10975).

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can I measure the frequency of motor vibration??

Comment: A small resistor (1 ohm or so) in series with the motor will give you a way of converting current to voltage. The current through the motor will change somewhat as it vibrates, at the same frequency as the vibration. Hence if you AC-couple the voltage across the series resistor into an oscilloscope, the fundamental frequency of that waveform should equal the frequency of vibration.